# CMake - How to add opencv_contrib to code?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to get this code to run https://github.com/Katou2/Optical_Flow_GPU_Opencv3/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt. I have zero experience with CMake, seem unable to understand the most basic tutorials and have spent more than a day trying to make it work with no success.

This is the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)
#set(OpenCV_DIR /home/pedro/opencv-3.1.0/build)
# QT5 insert

  # Tell CMake to run moc when necessary:
  set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
  # As moc files are generated in the binary dir, tell CMake
  # to always look for includes there:
  set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

  # Widgets finds its own dependencies (QtGui and QtCore).
  find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

  # The Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES also includes the include directories for
  # dependencies QtCore and QtGui
  include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})

  # We need add -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB when using QtWidgets in Qt 5.
  add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

  # Executables fail to build with Qt 5 in the default configuration
  # without -fPIE. We add that here.
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

# OpenCV Config
SET(OpenCV_DIR "/home/pedro/opencv-2.4.13.6/build")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message("-- OPENCV include:   " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("-- OPENCV libs dir:  " ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
message("-- OPENCV libs:   " ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDEBUG -ggdb -O3 -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fbranch-probabilities)

if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

################################

option(WARP ON)
if(WARP)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(
      compute_flow_si_warp
      compute_flow_si_warp.cpp
      ${SRCS}
    )

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
      compute_flow_si_warp
      ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}
      ${OpenCV_LIBS}
      ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}
    )
else()
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(
      compute_flow
      compute_flow.cpp
      ${SRCS}
    )

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
      compute_flow
      ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}
      ${OpenCV_LIBS}
      ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}
    )
endif()
################################

foreach(dir ${DIRS})
  FILE(GLOB files ${dir}/*.h*)
  LIST(APPEND h_files ${files})
endforeach(dir)
add_custom_target(TAGS etags --members -l c++ ${h_files} ${SRCS})
```

which when run via `cmake ..`

gives the following output, indicating that it has found the opencv folder.

```
--     version: 4.1.0
-- OPENCV include:   /usr/include/opencv4
-- OPENCV libs dir:
-- OPENCV libs:   opencv_calib3dopencv_coreopencv_dnnopencv_features2dopencv_flannopencv_gapiopencv_highguiopencv_imgcodecsopencv_imgprocopencv_mlopencv_objdetectopencv_photoopencv_stitchingopencv_videoopencv_videoioopencv_arucoopencv_bgsegmopencv_bioinspiredopencv_ccalibopencv_datasetsopencv_dnn_objdetectopencv_dpmopencv_faceopencv_fuzzyopencv_hdfopencv_hfsopencv_img_hashopencv_line_descriptoropencv_optflowopencv_phase_unwrappingopencv_plotopencv_qualityopencv_regopencv_rgbdopencv_saliencyopencv_shapeopencv_stereoopencv_structured_lightopencv_superresopencv_surface_matchingopencv_textopencv_trackingopencv_videostabopencv_xfeatures2dopencv_ximgprocopencv_xobjdetectopencv_xphoto
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/haziq/Downloads/Optical_Flow_GPU_Opencv3/build
```

The `make` command however, gives me the following output

```
[ 25%] Automatic MOC for target compute_flow
[ 25%] Built target compute_flow_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target compute_flow
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/compute_flow.dir/compute_flow.o
/home/haziq/Downloads/Optical_Flow_GPU_Opencv3/compute_flow.cpp:38:35: fatal error: opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/compute_flow.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/compute_flow.dir/compute_flow.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/compute_flow.dir/compute_flow.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/compute_flow.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/compute_flow.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

A quick search on google tells me that CMake has not detected the `opencv_contrib` files. Here is where my `opencv_contrib` files are located.

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "cudaoptflow.hpp"
/opencv_contrib-4.1.0/modules/cudaoptflow/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp
```

So how do I have CMake find it? I have tried many combinations to specify the path to `opencv_contrib` with no success.

Steps I took:

```
sudo ./install_opencv41_ubuntu.sh # from https://gist.github.com/kylehounslow/73c9e5b22c0421a27a17891b9064b0e7
git clone https://github.com/Katou2/Optical_Flow_GPU_Opencv3/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt
cd Optical_Flow_GPU_Opencv3
mkdir build
cd build
```

I ran several combinations of cmake and make but with no success.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opencv_contrib-4.1.0/modules -D BUILD_TIFF=ON ..
make
```

and

```
cmake ..
make
```

I notice that I have several OpenCV files.

```
/usr/include/opencv4/
/opencv-4.1.0/         
/opencv_contrib-4.1.0/
```

I believe I might have installed it multiple times during my blind attempts. How do I correct this?

Important:

Running the command

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opencv_contrib-4.1.0/modules/cudaoptflow/include/opencv2/ -D BUILD_TIFF=ON ..
```

returns the message

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH
```

Is this why it hasn't worked all this while? How do I fix this? How do I make the code use this variable?

Comment: `set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)` find_package should set this variable

Comment: @drescherjm thank you. So does that mean that my opencv_contrib has not been properly installed? Because in Python I can import headers from the opencv_contrib module.

Comment: ***quick search on google tells me that CMake has not detected the opencv_contrib files.*** Did you build these when you configured and built opencv with CMake? I think your problem is in steps you don't show.

Comment: @drescherjm I did not build opencv with CMake. I simply installed OpenCV using pip install opencv-python. Then I saw from the message output of message("-- OPENCV include: " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}) that CMake has detected the OpenCV folder.

And sorry I have little to no experience with CMake and C++, only Python.

Comment: I will update the thread with the full steps that I did in a few minutes.

Comment: OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path>

Comment: @drescherjm I have updated my post with more information, including the steps I did although it is missing some information as I might have installed opencv multiple times.

Comment: @Miki thank you for your suggestion. I did already try that before. This is the command I that I tried "cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opencv_contrib-4.1.0 -D BUILD_TIFF=ON .." but I get the message saying "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project: OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH"

Comment: I have updated the post again regarding the message "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project: OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH". I believe (and hope) that this is the final error message to the solution.

Comment: I have tried a bunch of stuffs and they have all failed. I remain utterly clueless.

Comment: ok... in this project you're **using** OpenCV, so you should just link to it. What you're doing here is already correct. The issue is that you don't have OpenCV build with controb modules. Pick any tutorial online for that, then link your project to it

Comment: @Miki thank you for the assurance. I have already ran this script https://gist.github.com/kylehounslow/73c9e5b22c0421a27a17891b9064b0e7 which installs OpenCV 4.1.0 with the contrib modules. Is this correct? My OpenCV folders are located at opencv-4.1.0/ and opencv_contrib-4.1.0/

Comment: yeah seems fine. You may want to use version 4.3.0 instead of 4.1.0, but it's ok.

Comment: @Miki Okay the issue is still here after I ran that script (I showed the steps that I took in my post). Might I have installed multiple OpenCV versions and now need to point CMake to the correct one with the contrib modules ?

Comment: I apologize if my questions seem extremely stupid. The only commands I were taught in school were to install anaconda for Python. And then we immediately went into coding. I will try to run the script from https://gist.github.com/kylehounslow/73c9e5b22c0421a27a17891b9064b0e7 and to run cmake again.

Comment: I reinstalled OpenCV and i still cannot fix my problem. A line-by-line instruction would be really nice. Anyone wants 500 points ?

Comment: I dont know what I am doing wrong. This is extremely disheartening. Could someone please just try to get it to run then write down the list of commands you did to make it work.......

Comment: I recommend that you do not beg here. I appreciate that being stuck for lengthy periods can be frustrating, but messages about how easy it would be for an expert, or how disheartened you are, may be read as emotional blackmail. Remember that your readership are volunteers, and that any help at all is a kindness. If you are still having problems, apply your bounty - that should get some attention.